# insert multiple rows is slow in symfony 3

Tags: symfony

I am doing insert multiple rows in symfony. My code inserts very slowly. Does anyone have any ideas that won't help me! Thank you !

```
                    $manager = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
                    // data : object
                    foreach ($data as $value) {
                        $entitty = $stkModel->getRepository()->findOneBy(['phone' => $value->getPhone()]);
                        if ($entity) {
                            $stk = $stkModel->getEntity();
                            $stk->setName('mina');
                            $stk->setStatus(1);
                            $manager->persist($stk);
                            $manager->flush();
                        }
                        if ($stk) {
                            $entitty = $titleModel->getRepository()->findOneBy(['stkId' => $stk->getId()]);
                            $title = $titleModel->getEntity();
                            $title->setName('dev');
                            $title->setOrder(2);
                            $manager->persist($title);
                            $manager->flush();
                        }
                        // Here I take $title->getId();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to call `persist` only at entities that are created with `new`. But this will not give you speed performance.

The `flush` slows the application down every time you use it, because here the query will be send to the database. To speed up your application you have to minimize the use of `flush`. In your case, just do one `flush` after you updated your entites.

```php
$manager = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
// data : object
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $entitty = $stkModel->getRepository()->findOneBy(['phone' => $value->getPhone()]);
    if ($entity) {
        $stk = $stkModel->getEntity();
        $stk->setName('mina');
        $stk->setStatus(1);
        // $manager->persist($stk); <-- Don't need persist here because your object is coming out from the entity manager
    }
    if ($stk) {
        $entitty = $titleModel->getRepository()->findOneBy(['stkId' => $stk->getId()]);
        $title = $titleModel->getEntity();
        $title->setName('dev');
        $title->setOrder(2);
        // $manager->persist($stk); <-- same as mention above
    }
}

// call flush once at the end
$manager->flush();
```

In some cases, you need to call flush in every loop in a foreach. That might happen if you need to query it. But in your case you just search for a id, which didn't change anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! I call flush 2 times because the 2nd if will get the save result of the 1st if and the 2nd if it saves I keep getting the id of the $title I shoot on the queue. Can you give me any suggestions? Sorry, I'm not good at English

Comment: Hmm, not easy to help you here, because it really depends on what is around your code. But you have to reduce your flush calls to improve your speed.